# Samsung enable disable "Driving mode"

Tags: android, mode, samsung-mobile, settings.settings

I would like to enable/disable **Driving mode** which is available on some Samsung devices (Galaxy S2, S3). I know I have to put something to system settings, but I don´t know what. So please advice me what values I should use or where I can find this information.

`Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), "something1", "something2");`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sure! This code works for me:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "driving_mode_on", 1); // To Enable
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "driving_mode_on", 0); // To Disable
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "driving_mode_on", isEnabled ? 0 : 1); // To Toggle
```

Use this app to know settings name on your device:
[Display System Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.SmartDyne.Free.DisplaySystemSettings)

Comment: Please replace your link to this link, because your link show it in IT and we all don´t understand : )
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.SmartDyne.Free.DisplaySystemSettings

Comment: @ThomasDiCristofaro It doesn't work on s5, do you know how to do it with s5?