# Android: How I can detect Driving Mode state on Samsung Galaxy S2, S3, S4 devices

Tags: android, galaxy

I want to detect is Driving Mode enabled/disabled state on my Samsung Galaxy S2, S3 or S4 devices programmaticaly, but I have no idea how I can do it.

P.S.: I mean: Settings > Language and input > Text-to-speech output > Driving Mode.

Please help.

Comment: What is "driving mode"? Do you mean whether your device is in a car dock? Do you mean whether the device appears to be in a moving vehicle? Do you mean something else?

Comment: Whatever it is, it would not appear to be part of standard Android, as I do not see it on a Galaxy Nexus. You may need to see if a Samsung-published SDK addresses your issue.

Comment: Seems to be I can get global preference value by `android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), s);` but I don't know what "s" string parameter should I use in this case.

Comment: Here is the almost same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519370/samsung-enable-disable-driving-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), 
            "driving_mode_on", 0) == 1;
```

isEnabled will be true if Driving Mode enabled